# Highlighting duplicates column by column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to go go through columns and highlight duplicates within the columns.
I used record macro to get an idea of what I need but I'm not sure how to apply this across many columns. Highlighting all columns won't work because many of the names repeat. I need to find out if a name repeats multiple times within a list.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub findDuplicates()
    Application.Goto Reference:="R3C18:R89C18"

    Application.Goto Reference:="R3C18:R88C18"
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16751204
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("R21").Select
End Sub
```

This is code I have that goes through each column within my range from B3:OA3 and sorts by color and alphabet. My thinking is that because this code goes column by column and sorts, I could simply add to it to highlight duplicates within the column it was already sorting. But I'm not sure how'd I'd do that.

```
Sub sortColorThenAlpha()
'sort by color then by alphabet

    Dim rngFirstRow As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngSort As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngFirstRow = ws.Range("B3:OA3")
    For Each rng In rngFirstRow.Cells
        With ws.Sort

            Set rngSort = rng.Resize(86, 1) 'to row 88

            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add(rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                            SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                            Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rngSort
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

        End With
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is what I'm looking at. That yellow conditinal formatting is what I'm trying to apply to each column between row 3 and 88. [image]

Comment: Upload the image to some external source, it's way to small

Comment: What's wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: The code I have here is just me manually selecting a range of cells in a column and applying conditional formatting. It's not an automated process I can just run starting from the first column.

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not seem necessary as Conditional Formatting with the following rules seems to work:

```
=A1=VLOOKUP(A1,A2:A$99,1,FALSE) Applies to: =$A$1:$J$99
=A2=VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:A1,1,FALSE)  Applies to: =$A$2:$J$99
```

with references adjusted to suit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to highlight duplicates in a single column, and you want to be able to automatically apply this formatting to all columns in a given sheet. So if Cleopatra appears once in several columns, she won't be highlighted, but if she appears more than once in a single column, she will.

The following code does just that. I'm finding the last column by looking for a value in row 3.

```
Sub HighlightDupesOneColumnAtATime()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim myColumn As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim columnCount As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dupeColor As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    columnCount = ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    dupeColor = 9944516

    For i = 1 To columnCount
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Call HighlightDupesInRange(dupeColor, Cells(1, i).Resize(lastRow, 1))
        ' it is easy to change the color of the 
        ' highlighted duplicates if you want
        dupeColor = dupeColor + 15
    Next i
End Sub

Sub HighlightDupesInRange(cellColor As Long, rng As Range)
    With rng
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = cellColor
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```